# Node js router async and await is not working

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, backend, router

I have a problem in my code. The program skips the for loop every time in the function. So, I tried to add async and but now I get an error message all the time. This is the error message:

> result = await GetAnrede(result)
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Here are the database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw9Fi.png)

Here is my code

```
//Anrede = Salutation
function GetAnrede(result){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++){
        db.query(`SELECT anrede FROM tblanrede WHERE anredeid = ${db.escape(result[i].anredeid)}`,
        (anredeErr, anredeResult) => {
                 result[i].anredeid = anredeResult[0].anrede
            }
        )
    }
    return result
}

//Lehrer = Teacher
router.get("/GetLehrer",  async function(req, res, next){
  db.query(`SELECT lehrerkuerzel, anredeid, vorname, nachname FROM tbllehrer`,
    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send({
                msg: err
            })
        }

        if(!result.length){
            return res.status(400).send({
                msg: "In der Datenbank sind keine Lehrer vorhanden."
            })
        } else {
            result = await GetAnrede(result)
            console.log(result)
            return res.status(200).send({
               result
            })
        }
    }
)})
```

Comment: Your `await` is in the DB query callback--that's a different function than the route handling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
//Anrede = Salutation
async function GetAnrede(result){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++){
        await db.query(`SELECT anrede FROM tblanrede WHERE anredeid = ${db.escape(result[i].anredeid)}`,
            (anredeErr, anredeResult) => {
                result[i].anredeid = anredeResult[0].anrede
            }
        )
     }

    return result;
}

//Lehrer = Teacher
router.get("/GetLehrer",  async function(req, res, next){
  await db.query(`SELECT lehrerkuerzel, anredeid, vorname, nachname FROM tbllehrer`,
    async (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).send({
                msg: err
            })
        }

        if(!result.length){
            return res.status(400).send({
                msg: "In der Datenbank sind keine Lehrer vorhanden."
            })
        } else {
            result = await GetAnrede(result)
            console.log(result)
            return res.status(200).send({
               result
            })
        }
    }
)})
```